# Change camera preview shape in android

Tags: android, camera

What I want to do is "simply" get the camera preview (which is already working) and then put it inside a roundish shape for example, so that instead of appearing on a rectangle shape it would appear, on a round one, for example in the top corner.This camera preview is inside a custom view. Also, there is another custom view that runs behind the camera preview, which is a video, as the image: (black -> camera preview, green -> video)

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

After searching a while for solutions to this problem I did not come to any conclusion that works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try using corner radius of the shape. it can be useful